# BDD : Test using Sclatest - AnyFlatSpec and Junit 5 not detected

Tags: java, scala, bdd, scalatest, junit-jupiter

I'm using :

- scala 2.12.15
- Java 17
- scalatest_2.12:3.2.15
- JUnit 5
- Gradle

With this very simple codes in my test folder:

```
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec


class MyTestSpec extends AnyFlatSpec {

  "An empty Set" should "have size 0" in {
    assert(Set.empty.size === 0)
  }
}
```

when I try to execute this test, I have : **No tests found...**

When I Use Junit 4, it's OK, but with Junit 5, KO.

**remark **:
In my gradle, I have :

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Is AnyFlatSpec don't support JUnit 5 ? Is there another solution ?

Thanks for your help !